# How do I make a NavTypeSerializer for a lambda for Compose Destinations?

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, jetpack-compose-navigation

I am trying to pass a simple lambda of type `(Item) -> Boolean` as a navigation argument. However, it seems like Compose Destinations does not recognize the `NavTypeSerializer` I made.

```
@NavTypeSerializer
class ItemToBooleanNavTypeSerializer : DestinationsNavTypeSerializer<(Item) -> Boolean> {
    override fun toRouteString(value: (Item) -> Boolean): String =
        Json.encodeToString(value)

    override fun fromRouteString(routeStr: String): (Item) -> Boolean =
        Json.decodeFromString(routeStr)
}
```

Here is my `navArgsDelegate`:

```
data class AddCustomBookNavArgs(
    val target: Item,
    val isBookCompatible: (book: Item) -> Boolean,
    val addCustomBook: (book: Item) -> Boolean,
)
```

It gives me this error:

```
[ksp] com.ramcosta.composedestinations.codegen.commons.IllegalDestinationsSetup: Composable 'AddCustomBookScreen': 'navArgsDelegate' cannot have arguments that are not navigation types.
    at com.ramcosta.composedestinations.codegen.commons.DestinationWithNavArgsMapper.getNavArgs(DestinationWithNavArgsMapper.kt:26)
    at com.ramcosta.composedestinations.codegen.commons.DestinationWithNavArgsMapper.map(DestinationWithNavArgsMapper.kt:14)
    at com.ramcosta.composedestinations.codegen.CodeGenerator.generate(CodeGenerator.kt:37)
    at com.ramcosta.composedestinations.ksp.processors.Processor.process(Processor.kt:48)
```

I tried checking if `NavTypeSerializer` is working with non-lambda types, like `Color`, as shown in the documentation and it works just fine. I don't know how to make it work with lambdas.

This works as expected:

```
@NavTypeSerializer
class Serializer : DestinationsNavTypeSerializer<Color> {
    override fun toRouteString(value: Color): String =
        Json.encodeToString(value)

    override fun fromRouteString(routeStr: String): Color =
        Json.decodeFromString(routeStr)
}

data class AddCustomBookNavArgs(
    val edition: Edition,
    val target: Item,
    val color: Color,
)
```

Compose Destinations: https://github.com/raamcosta/compose-destinations

Official documentation:
https://composedestinations.rafaelcosta.xyz/destination-arguments/navigation-arguments#custom-navigation-argument-types

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trying to serialize lambdas will never work. Even if it did, the one who is listening for this callback to be called would not get notified because in the end, the callback instance passed to the destination would not be the same.

You can share the same view model on both destinations.
For that, you can define a nested navigation graph that both of them belong to. Then you can scope your ViewModel to that navigation graph and both of them can access it.

On the documentation link you posted, you will find examples of sharing the ViewModel with multiple destinations.

Comment: My problem with this is if I make a nested NavGraph for DestinationA and DestinationB, DestinationA must be a "start" destination. However, DestinationA requires mandatory navigation arguments, and start destinations do not allow mandatory navigation arguments.

Comment: I currently work around this by giving them default arguments. However, defaults do not make sense in this context. I wish there is a more sophisticated solution.

Comment: Then you’ll be glad knowing that soon enough nested graphs’ start destinations will allow mandatory arguments :) I’m currently working on it.

Comment: Another way that could work depending on the exact use case is accessing the VM of the previous back stack entry. You can do “navController.previousBackStackEntry” and you pass that to the viewModel getter method. This way you don’t need a nested nav graph :)

Comment: Okay, I'll stick with giving my arguments defaults for now while waiting for your library to support mandatory args for nested start destinations. Thank you so much for this wonderful library. It made my life so much easier.